# error by node and mongodb

Tags: javascript, macos, node.js, mongodb

when I start my JS file, I get the follow error:

```
Charon:modules Modius$ node testfile.js 

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/spacebattles/server/modules/testfile.js:11:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
Charon:modules Modius$
```

and here the js file

```
define(['./db_user'], function (db_user) {

    var db_user = document.createElement("db_user.js");
    var tranfer = {
        login: "test" ,
        email: "holishitumsonst.com",
        password: "123nu"
    };
    db_user.insert(transfer);

});
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may misunderstood the concept of node. Like Florian sayed, node.js is "only" the V8 engine withouth a browser around it. This means you have no document (no DOM at all).

To get started with node.js I recommend you to look into O'Reilly's [Up and running with node.js](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449398583/). The modular system is explained there, too.

In Order to use MongoDB with node you have to use packages like mongoose or mongolian installed through npm. Both are explained in the book I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the way you've used it, it seems you're trying to use [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/).

Node.js is not client-side code. You don't need Require.js, there is already `require` available.

Usage example:

```
// Loads the mongodb-client module in the "mongo" variable
var mongo = require('mongodb-client');
```

Also, there is no `document` available, you're not in a browser, there is no DOM either. If you want one, you can use [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom), but I don't think this is what you want.

To sum it up: stop thinking you're in a browser. You're not. There is no `document`, no `window`, no need for custom loading, you can just program in a server environment.

I'd highly suggest you to read [Node Beginner](http://www.nodebeginner.org/).

> The aim of this document is to get you started with developing applications with Node.js, teaching you everything you need to know about "advanced" JavaScript along the way. It goes way beyond your typical "Hello World" tutorial.